# How to saveOrUpdateAll in Spring(4.2.5.RELEASE)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In `Spring 3.1.4.RELEASE`'s `HibernateDaoSupport`, there was a method called `saveOrUpdateAll`. It is used to save a collection. But in 4.2.5.release it's gone. Now I can't find the proper way to save/update a collection. Can you give me a site to figure it out?

Comment: There is not `HibernateDaoSupport` in Hibernate. It always resides in Spring.

Comment: @v.ladynev yes, I'm fix my question now

Comment: loop through the collection, and call saveOrUpdate() on every element. What's the difficulty?

Comment: @JBNizet I googled it and know what's going on with the saveOrUpdateAll. I thought that the method did a good job and it was just a function to deal everything. I was wrong. I'm trying your suggestion

Comment: That method was part of the `HibernateTemplate` and basically the use of `HIbernateTemplate` should be avoided (at least it isn't recommended anymore). You should use a plain `SessionFactory` instead and then do what was suggested in a different comment.

Comment: @M.Deinum could you give me some thing about using the sessionFactory instead of hibernate template? I wanna know more about it

Comment: See the reference guide -> http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight (is about Hibernate 3 but applies to all hibernate versions).

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks. I found that there are a lot of thing I should read. I'm reviewing the source code. A lot of things are deprected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely are constructing a `SessionFactory` in your XML configuration or in your Java configuration, depending on your taste.  You simply need to inject your `SessionFactory` into your repository bean and use it.

A simplistic example could look like:

```
@Repository
public class SomeEntityRepository {
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  // Constructor-injection injects a SessionFactory
  @Autowired
  public SomeEntityRepository(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sesssionFactory = sessionFactory;
  }

  // uses SessionFactory to get the current session, iterates the collection
  // and calls saveOrUpdate on each instance inside the collection.
  public void saveOrUpdateAll(Collection<?> collection) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    for(Object object : collection) {
      session.saveOrUpdate(object);
    }       
  }
}
```